# Highest thread priority and infinite loop without sleep in Windows

Tags: windows, multithreading, thread-priority

I've been reading about thread priorities on MSDN and I created a test program that has two threads. One of the threads prints out some text and then sleeps while the other thread runs an infinite loop where it increments some number and does so without sleep. I set the latter thread to have a higher priority than the former and according to what I'm reading this should means that the former thread doesn't get any CPU-time.

But it does..

Why is this?

The first thread is created using:

```
HANDLE threadL = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadLow, NULL, 0, &threadLiD);
```

and the other thread is just the main thread where I've put this command:

```
SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);
```

Comment: Since you're unlikely to run this on a single core system (VM would work), have you made sure that the OS assigns only a single core to your program? (You can do that in the taskmanager and also programatically somehow). Otherwise you obviously will be able to run more than one thread at a time ;)

Comment: Note also that the Windows scheduling alorithm does have an anti-starvation alogorithm that will, after 30 seconds, apply a temporary boost to the priority of low-prio ready threads that have been unable to run at all for that interval. This will give a minimal amout of CPU to your low-prio thread even on a single-core system.

Comment: @Voo - careful if you do this.  Some virtualizers allow more than one core to be mapped to a VM.

Comment: @Martin oh all i know of certainly allow that, but you can pretty easily create a VM that only uses a single core. Should've made that clearer I guess.

Comment: Turns out that it's not supposed to lock itself in the high priority thread. The Windows schedular preempts the thread and gives other threads CPU-time based on their given time quantum.